# Removing duplicates rows in left Joining query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

```
      SELECT Rec.[Reg_ID]
      ,Rec.[Reg_No]
      ,Rec.[Case_ID]
      ,Det.Deleted AS CaseDeleted
      ,[Status].[Status]
      ,Det.[Unit_Submission_Date] AS [Signature]
      ,TD.TargetDate AS [Target]
      ,TD.TargetID
      FROM [dbo].[Regestrations] Rec
      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Reg_Details] Det ON Rec.Case_ID   = Det.CaseID
      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[lkpStatus] [Status] ON Rec.Status_ID = [Status].StatusID
      LEFT JOIN TargetDate TD ON TD.RecommId = Rec.Reg_ID
      WHERE (Det.MissionID = 50 AND [Status].[Status] = 1 AND Rec.Deleted = 0 AND Det.Deleted = 0)
      GROUP BY Rec.[Reg_ID],Rec.[Reg_No],Rec.[Case_ID]
      ,[Status].[Status]
      ,Det.[Unit_Submission_Date]
      ,TD.TargetDate
      ,Det.Deleted
      ,TD.TargetID
      ORDER BY TD.TargetID desc
```

I have the above query that is supposed to return rows with unique `Rec.[Reg_No]`.  But joined table `TargetDate` can have duplicate `Rec.[Reg_ID]` and if thats the case i get duplicate `Rec.[Reg_No]` rows in my results.

Table `TargetDate` has a date time column so i want to eliminate the duplicate `Rec.[Reg_No]` by selecting 1 row with the latest date value from table `TargetDate`.

How do modify my Join condition or the query where clause to achive the above?

Comment: Assuming the rows are true duplicates, have you tried using "Distinct" after the "Select" to ensure no duplicate rows (i.e. Select distinct)? If that doesn't work, please post some sample duplicate rows for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query can work correctly if you remove `TD.TargetDate` from `GROUP BY` clause and compute what you really need in output - `MAX(TD.TargetDate)`

But preferable way it to avoid `GROUP BY` clause at all:

```
  ...
  FROM [BOI].[dbo].[Regestrations] Rec
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Reg_Details] Det ON Rec.Case_ID   = Det.CaseID
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[lkpStatus] [Status] ON Rec.Status_ID = [Status].StatusID
  OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 td.TargetDate, td.TargetID
    FROM TargetDate TD
    WHERE TD.RecommId = Rec.Reg_ID
    ORDER BY TD.TargetDate DESC
  ) td
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a window function such as `ROW_NUMBER()` that will generate sequential number based on the specified partition. This generated number can then be used to get the latest row.

```
SELECT  Reg_ID, Reg_No, Case_ID, CaseDeleted, [Status], Signature, [Target], TargetID
FROM
(
    SELECT Rec.[Reg_ID]
            ,Rec.[Reg_No]
            ,Rec.[Case_ID]
            ,Det.Deleted AS CaseDeleted
            ,[Status].[Status]
            ,Det.[Unit_Submission_Date] AS [Signature]
            ,TD.TargetDate AS [Target]
            ,TD.TargetID
            ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rec.[Reg_No] ORDER BY TD.TargetID DESC)
    FROM [BOI].[dbo].[Regestrations] Rec
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Reg_Details] Det ON Rec.Case_ID   = Det.CaseID
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[lkpStatus] [Status] ON Rec.Status_ID = [Status].StatusID
        LEFT JOIN TargetDate TD ON TD.RecommId = Rec.Reg_ID
    WHERE (Det.MissionID = 50 AND [Status].[Status] = 1 AND Rec.Deleted = 0 AND Det.Deleted = 0)

) subQuery
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY TargetID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first find latest TargetDate for each `Reg_ID` or `RecommId`. Then you can use your normal join with TargetDate table just this time with matching both the `RecommId` and `TargetDate`.

**Try this Query:**

```
SELECT Rec.[Reg_ID]
      ,Rec.[Reg_No]
      ,Rec.[Case_ID]
      ,Det.Deleted AS CaseDeleted
      ,[Status].[Status]
      ,Det.[Unit_Submission_Date] AS [Signature]
      ,TD.TargetDate AS [Target]
      ,TD.TargetID

FROM [BOI].[dbo].[Regestrations] Rec
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Reg_Details] Det ON Rec.Case_ID   = Det.CaseID
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[lkpStatus] [Status] ON Rec.Status_ID = [Status].StatusID
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT RecommId, MAX(TargetDate) MaxTargetDate GROUP BY RecommId) TDWithLatestDate ON TDWithLatestDate.RecommId = Rec.Reg_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TargetDate ON TD.RecommId = TDWithLatestDate.RecommId AND TD.TargetDate = TDWithLatestDate.MaxTargetDate

WHERE (Det.MissionID = 50 
       AND [Status].[Status] = 1
       AND Rec.Deleted = 0 
       AND Det.Deleted = 0
      )

GROUP BY Rec.[Reg_ID]
            ,Rec.[Reg_No]
            ,Rec.[Case_ID]
            ,[Status].[Status]
            ,Det.[Unit_Submission_Date]
            ,TD.TargetDate
            ,Det.Deleted
            ,TD.TargetID

ORDER BY TD.TargetID desc
```

You can improve this query if you want to avoid tie when there more than one record fighting to be latest.